# Does VLOOKUP work for booleans?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a small problem with VLOOKUP in Excel. Suppose we have the following sheet:

[image]

Now column E only contains numbers and column F contains formula's such as: "=E6 = 3", since my favorite number is 3. These are all logical values, determined with the ISLOGICAL function in Excel.

Now I would like to do a VLOOKUP(TRUE, E6:F13, 1). I would expect it to be 3, but I get an #N/A. How can I use VLOOKUP to compare logical values?

Some of you suggested me that VLOOKUP only searches in the first column. Now if we swap column F with column E, we get something like (note: I have moved the columns slightly):

[image]

The 8 does not make sense to me. Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: What about using a count it? I do not think Vlookup will take a Boolean.

Comment: Well, I would like to find a boolean value that equals to true and then return the value associated with it in another column.

Comment: You need to add false as the last parameter in your second scenario. VLOOKUP returns "TRUE" as a value of 1, so it is not picking up your lookup value as a match unless you enter false. You want: =VLOOKUP(TRUE,D6:E13,2,FALSE)

Comment: That being said, INDEX:MATCH works in either scenario, as shown in my answer below. It is a much more capable alternative to VLOOKUP in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDEX:MATCH in place of vlookup:

```
=INDEX(E6:E13,MATCH(TRUE,F6:F13,0))
```

[image]

EDIT:
For your revised layout you can use:

```
=INDEX(E6:E13,MATCH(TRUE,D6:D13,0))
```

[image]

EDIT 2:

Just for clarity, VLOOKUP will work with booleans with the revised layout:

```
=VLOOKUP(TRUE,D6:E13,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` works from left to right, you are looking for a value from right to left, so it won't work. Even if you exchange `Favorite` and `Number` columns, it won't work, as `VLOOKUP` seems to not work properly with boolean values.

Comment: VLOOKUP does work with booleans with the revised layout. You are correct about the left to right issue though. =VLOOKUP(TRUE,D6:E13,2,FALSE) works, but the last parameter is needed to make it work.